# Sending a message in QuickFIX

Tags: quickfix

I am using the python code examples from "http://www.quickfixengine.org" and have a question. I create my application using the code segment shown below

```
import quickfix

if len(sys.argv) < 2: return
fileName = sys.argv[1]

try:
    settings = quickfix.SessionSettings(fileName)
    application = quickfix.MyApplication()
    storeFactory = quickfix.FileStoreFactory(settings)
    logFactory = quickfix.FileLogFactory(settings)
    initiator = quickfix.SocketInitiator(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)
    initiator.start()
    # while condition == true: do something
    initiator.stop()
except quickfix.ConfigError, e:
    print e
```

The connection is made and I get logged in, and now I want to send a message (an order, for example). The provided code segment for that is:

```
def sendOrderCancelRequest:
    message = quickfix.Message();
    header = message.getHeader();

    header.setField(...)
    *<...build the header and body...>*
    message.setField(...)

    Session.sendToTarget(message)
```

My question is about that `Session` object. Where/How is that created? Does it get created with something like `Session = quickfix.Session()`, or something else that they are not showing? I've tried a few things, but with the dearth of documentation its just trial and error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session` is not an *object*, it's a *class*.  In this case, `sendToTarget()` is static method.

`Session`, maintains a class-static list of sessions.  `sendToTarget()`'s uses the header fields in your message (or those you explicitly supply) to determine which session to send on.

---

**EDIT: I misread your question.  Here's an answer to what you asked.**

The session is created in the bowels of the QF engine.  It's created by a `SessionFactory`, which is itself created in the `initialize()` function of `Initiator` and `Acceptor`.  This is stuff you only need to get into if you feel like hacking on the engine source.

As an app developer, you really don't need a handle to the session.  If you think you do, then I'm guessing you're probably planning to do something that is not recommended (such as wanting to programmatically reset seq#s, which is a common newbie Bad Idea on the QF lists).

If you really want a handle to it, you can use `Session.lookupSession()` or one of the `getSession()` functions of `Initiator` or `Acceptor`.  But again, I don't see any reason to bother.  I'm a seasoned QF user, and I had to go look this up, because it's something *I never ever do*.

Comment: Thanks @grant. I understand that `sendToTarget()` is a method in `Session`, my question is where is the instance of the class is created. No where in the code (that I posted) is anything with the name "Session" created so that it can be used.

Comment: @gearhead - my bad, I misunderstood.  See my update to the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Grant. I figured it was created behind the scenes. I get errors when I use the code from the QuickFIX site. When it gets to that line I get a run-time error:

`"NameError: name 'Session' is not defined"`
Which makes sense because I never create anything with that name...

I think I figured it out though. If instead I use:

`quickfix.Session_sendToTarget(message)`

Everything _seems_ to work

Thanks again @Grant. I really appreciate all the help and advice you have given in my last few posts.

Comment: That underscore thing must be a convention created for the Python wrapper.  And you're welcome for the help!